# Change default "symbolic link" folder in laravel 5.4 (storage folder)

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, storage, directory

I'm making a new version of my site with laravel 5.4 and want to keep the same links than my old site has.

My old site has links images like this:
**domain.com/uploaded/cat.jpg**

In laravel, its necesary to create a **symbolic link** to show the stored images but it saved them with a default folder named **storage**", like this:
**domain.com/storage/cat.jpg**

How can i change the default name to "uploaded" or whatever?

I tried to change **url** inside the file *\config\filesystems.php* with this:

Before

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

After

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploaded',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

and my controller

```
$request->file('image')->storeAs('public', 'example.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've created a symlink.

According to your configuration, you can run this command :

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/uploaded
```

Then, you can access your files :

```
Storage::disk('public')->url('example.jpg')
```

Or simply using `asset()` helper :

```
asset('uploaded/example.jpg');
```

Comment: what is the difference between saving files inside "storage/public" (symbolic link) and the real public folder?

Comment: There is no difference, but it is a convention for the Filesystem - `This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.` [From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: i can't run thar command. It's for linux, right? i have windows

Comment: Indeed it's for Linux/Mac, but a similar Windows command exists, try : `mklink /d public\uploaded storage\app\public` (arguments are swapped for Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code in your server using any php file to create the symbolic link. Once the link has been created, the files will become publicly accessible.

target = '/home/cfrcoclm/public_html/agencies/storage/app/public'
shortcut = '/home/cfrcoclm/public_html/agencies/uploaded'
symlink(target, shortcut)
ec ho("Link Created!")
`

Answer (score 0):

In case you **do not have SSH access**, you can as well write this one-line script below and run it on your server - taking into consideration the right directory path

symlink('/home/domainname/laravelprojectname/storage/app/public','/home/domainname/public_html/storage');